# Removing single quotes in PHP

Tags: php, quotes

I got some issues trying to INSERT some data from a php document till i got 2 values which contains quotes inside like :

"Rempli d'étoiles"

i d like to remove the ' by a space or even nothing.

-> "Rempli d etoiles"
Here is my what i tried :

```
$posdeapostrophe = strpos($array, '\'');
if ($posdeapostrophe == false) 
{
    ...
}
else
{
    // it goes in this block when it detects a ', but seems like trim doesnt work as i would

    $newchaine =  trim($array, '\'');
    $sql .=  "INSERT INTO categorie (id_cat,name_cat) VALUES (" . $cpt . ",'" .$newchaine . "'); ";
```

thanks!

Comment: [`$your_string = str_replace("'", "", $your_string);`](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: You could alternatively try escaping strings for SQL context. Or switch to a more recent database API and use bound parameters for simplicity.

Comment: Why, is it throwing an error? (*Most likely is*). Escape your values, or better yet, use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). and you will be able to enter that very same string in your DB without having to use that extra function, plus it will be safer.

Comment: use prepared queries or `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.... `mysql_real_esacpe_string()` if you are using older version. but change it to atleast `mysqli` as soon as possible.

Comment: str_replace worked fine. well, i'm kinda new in php, thanks for the pdo documentation, i ll check it out.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `stripslashes()`, another option if you don't feel ready for prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_replace()`.

```
$array = "Some string's";
$posdeapostrophe = strpos($array, "'");
$val = '';
if ($posdeapostrophe !== false)
{
    $val = str_replace("'", "\'", $array);
}
echo $val;
```

Also can use instead of `strpos()` and `replace()` to escape single quotes.

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $array ); //for mysqli
mysql_real_escape_string($array , $con); //for mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is quite dangerous.

First of all, you should really use the current recommended method for executing queries which is by using PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

This will both solve the quotes problem and a massive security hole (SQLi vulnerability) you have currently introduced in your code.

If you still want to replace the single quotes in your text you can indeed do what @scrowler suggested which is:

`$your_string = str_replace("'", "", $your_string);`

But please use PDO when interacting with a database since this is really the only (safe and recommended) way of doing this.

Comment: i will try to learn it asap and change my way to do then, thanks for your help!